# Skipping Same Values when Reading csv into Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to subtract the previous item in a list from the following item in a list, but I think my type is preventing me from doing so. The type of each item in the list is int. If i have a list of integers such as

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

How will I subtract 1 from 2, 2 from 3, 3 from 4, etc., and print this value after each operation?

My list is torcount, which I acquired from a numpy operation, and this is the code I tried:

```
TorCount=len(np.unique(TorNum))
for i in range(TorCount):
    TorCount=TorCount[i]-TorCount[i-1]
    print TorCount
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen [np.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

**Example:**

```
>>> xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.diff(xs, n=1)
array([1, 1, 1])
```

> `numpy.diff(a, n=1, axis=-1)`
>
> Calculate the n-th order discrete difference along given axis.
>
> The first order difference is given by out[n] = a[n+1] - a[n]
>   along the given axis, higher order differences are calculated
>   by using diff recursively.